# Knockout validation of array (dynamic length) - how to?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array of objects, called Translations = { LangName, Translation}

In my html markup, I need to apply the red border only to the input fields that have failed validation. The number of input fields is dynamic. Here is my html markup

```html
<table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: methToChange.nameTranslations">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div class="method-lb-1"><label data-bind="text:LangName"></label></div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="method-left">
               <input type="text" class="input-xl" maxlength="40" placeholder="required"
                  onblur="validateEditNameTranslations()"
                  data-bind="value:Translation, css: { 'methods-border-error': FLAG } " />
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of the FLAG, I need a way to validate these dynamically generated fields - if that field failed validation, the flag is true and the red border will appear.

If there is a way to do with in knockout, that would be helpful. Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've posted. If there's a bug preventing it from working it's... in another castle.

Comment: @Jason, Ok I will ask again, maybe I wasn't clear - I need to somehow pass the element id or value into a validation function to make only the field that is failing red. Is there a way in Knockout to do this?

Comment: use this knockout validation plugin: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation. It works very well.

Comment: @sarsnake you want the validation on "render" or after someone fills in data ?